# Collision between wall and player controller

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, box2d, farseer

I'm using Farseer and XNA on on WP7. I have 2 objects in my game. The first one is a wall generated from a bitmap. The second one is a player controller - in fact it's just a circle object. This circle follows player's finger.

I need a certain behavior - probably it's very basic, but I can't figure out how to google it. It's a collision detection that just wouldn't allow the controller to come into the wall. It shouldn't bounce. It should just try to follow the finger but not enter the wall.

I know it's not hard to implement it on my own, but if I'm using a physics engine and it happens to offer such a functionality it would be a shame not to take advantage of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a BoundingBox object, and check collision VS the object (you should create a BoundingSphere wrapping it)

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Collision_detection.php